# How to fix duplicate symbol error in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

the variable is inside Constants.h

[image]

ERROR is:

```
duplicate symbol _OSVShortTermFuelTrim1 in:
/Users/loximity/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AutoCodesApp-hjoxbttreaujifdypikhbngdqihd/Build/Intermediates/AutoCodesApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AutoCodesApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
/Users/loximity/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AutoCodesApp-hjoxbttreaujifdypikhbngdqihd/Build/Intermediates/AutoCodesApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AutoCodesApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/FuelTrimViewController.o
```

and then I am using the above variables in two places, in view controller:

```
OSVShortTermFuelTrim1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [sensor valueStringForMeasurement1:NO], [sensor imperialUnitString]];
```

and in FuelTrimViewController"

```
fuelBank1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",OSVShortTermFuelTrim1];
```

Comment: @dandan78 dear if u cannot contribute, at least do not disappoint the person who's asking a question, how can this be a duplicate? as i have added my own code snippets.

Comment: @Adeel One could also possibly say if you don't understand the purpose of SO don't use it. The reason they have marked it as a duplicate is because it is the same sort of question and the answer can point you in the right direction. Also do you know what the term `CONSTANT` means? Why are you trying to reassign `OSVShortTermFuelTrim1` when you clearly state it is a constant in your `constant.h` file? Clearly it isn't a constant as you want to be able to reassign those values. Also a constant would be marked with the keyword `const` and `extern`. This `constant.h` file of yours is misleading.

Comment: @dandan78 finding an answer is easier then writing it down, i know how to use SO, instead of writing down a duplicate u could have answer this. Thanks anyways. if SO will keep expert guys like you then asking a question over google will result in a single answer by SO with no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `extern` to the declare the constants in the header file:

```
extern NSString *const YOUR_CONSTANT;
```

and then in an implementation file (`.m`), define the value:

```
NSString *const YOUR_CONSTANT = @"Hello World";
```

and, incidentally, your example code is the same, for all intents and purposes, to:

```
fuelBank1.text = OSVShortTermFuelTrim1;
```

Comment: or `#define YOUR_CONSTANT @"Hello World"` could also work.

Comment: @holex Depends how you test for equality.

Comment: in runtime such macro is allocated only once in the application's lifecycle, and they can be compared by their own _pointer_ or their _content_ as well, they would be identical eventually. if that is what you meant...

Comment: @holex i cannot get your answer

Comment: @holex That's true only within the execution unit; if the string was in a framework, for example, then your `#define` would fail testing by reference.

Comment: @trojanfoe, oh, yes! I can get you now.